# vb.net CreationTime of Office Interop ReportItem is not correct

Tags: vb.net, outlook, office-interop

I trying to read the creation time of a report item. When using ".CreationTime" however, the Last Modification Time is returned instead of the correct value. As the mails are moved to a different folder the time and date of this move is returned as creation time. Has anyone an idea why that is or if there is a workaround to get the creation time?

Here is some of my code, in this case I only print the creation time.

```
Dim oApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Namespace
Dim olTaskFolder As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olReportItem As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ReportItem
Dim olTemp As Object
Dim tableRow As DataRow

olNS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
olTaskFolder = olNS.Folders(mailBox).Folders(mainFolder)


For Each olTemp In olTaskFolder.Items
 If TypeName(olTemp).EndsWith("ReportItem") Then
  olReportItem=DirectCast(olTemp,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ReportItem)
  console.WriteLine("----")
  console.WriteLine(olReportItem.CreationTime.toString)
End If
```

Next

Answer (score 0):

If an items is moved between folders, its `CreationTime` and `LastModificationTime` can be modified. In general, these properties are preserved when moving between folders in the same mailbox, but moving between mailboxes can reset them.

Comment: Is there any way to get the initial CreationTime back? The correct time in which the email was sent is still visible in outlook itself. Is there a way to get to this value?

Comment: Sure, the received date will be intact.

Comment: A Reportitem doesn’t have a received date as far as I know

Comment: Only because the ReportItem object does not expose it as a property - you can still see it in OutlookSpy (click IMessage button) and access it through ReportItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty